# Do we have to wrap an infant in the warm clothes after his birth?

Tags: infant, health, clothes

My all relatives have been telling me that the inside of the womb is warm so when the baby comes out he needs to be wrapped from head to toe in warm clothes so that he doesn't get ill due to the temperature difference.

I would have followed that advise without being skeptical if it were cold here.

The room temperature here is *37 degree Celsius* and the outside temperature is *45 degree Celsius*. ***With this temperature range does it still make sense to follow that advise?

If yes, then for how many days?***

Is that advise based on any scientific facts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reasoning behind the wrapping is that the birth is quite an environmental change to the baby:
You're safe in a nice and warm and soft womb, but suddenly this is replaced by light and air and space and hands and surfaces. Wrapping the baby gives some comfort (although not all babies like being wrapped, they enjoy their newly-won freedom).

If you're in a very warm climate, you can wrap the baby in thin soft sheets. That should be enough. 
In colder climates, one could use towels or thicker cloths instead.
Regardless whether the baby is wrapped or not, make sure that the baby is **not too hot or too cold.**

You can feel "too hot" at the neck; the baby should feel nice and have a normal skin temperature, and not sweat. "Too cold" is easily noticed by touching the hands/fingers/feet.

You can wrap the baby like this for several months, as long as it's comfortable for you and the baby.

Comment: `make sure that the baby is not too hot or too cold.` What is the way to make sure that? sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: @user462608: My last paragraph tries to answer that question.

Comment: Yes, I read that and upvoted your answer.

Comment: My baby whined when she was too hot. It might be hard to understand at first, but eventually you'll pick up on their queues.

Answer (score 3):

The womb is 37 degrees, so there is no temperature difference.  It certainly feels different in liquid compared to air, but wrapping in cloth doesn't provide the same experience as being in liquid, except insomuch as it traps your perspiration, which doesn't seem like a very good idea in your circumstance.

In those sorts of temperatures, I would be *way* more concerned with the baby getting too hot than getting too cold.  You should get the advice of people local to you on how they deal with it.  How humid or arid your climate is will make a difference.  People with air conditioning or who live in different climates will have a different experience.

Comment: +1 for the obvious _get the advice of people local_ that nobody else mentioned :-)

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the baby also has a lot to do with comforting as well as keeping bub warm. Wrapping helps the baby settle and feel comforted and they usually sleep better when wrapped.

Have a read about [startle reflex](http://www.whattoexpect.com/first-year/video/why-babies-startle-so-easily.aspx#). Wrapping helps to avoid this.

With such warm temps, consider using muslin or some other kind of very breathable wrap. I've always followed the principle of the baby should wear what I would wear, + 1 layer.